# Invoking program through java jar used in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have one jar file which invokes certain console program.
I am using this jar file in Pig.
My problem is that it works fine in Local mode but when i enter into Hadoop mode it fails.
I have also made changes in bashrc at all nodes but similar error occurs always.
So how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials I got the answer.
Firstly copy the files into tmp folder of hdfs for e.g. *hadoop fs -put YourModule /tmp/*
Then in the pig script add statements as follows:
*SET mapred.cache.files /tmp/YourModule#ModuleName;
SET mapred.create.symlink yes;*

Then in jar file where you wan to access files inside those folder you can do by using path:
*ModuleName/filename*

thats it.
It works smoothly in hadoop similar to Local mode.