# Unable to run Pig Script in Psudo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I am trying to write a pig script.I have it successfully working in local mode, but getting error when I launch pig in Psudo-distributed mode.
Here is the script:

```
register 'myfolder/target/myfunc-with-dependencies.jar';
SET mapred.cache.files /tmp/scripts#scripts,/tmp/my_rules#my_rules;
SET mapred.create.symlink yes;

%default INPUT 'test.seq'
%default OUTPUT 'final.out'
%default TIMEOUT_MS '180000'
%default USE_DEVSHM 'true'

data = load '$INPUT' using com.pack.loaders.MyTextLoader('$TIMEOUT_MS');
STORE data INTO '$OUTPUT'
```

I get the following error:

```
2013-09-03 08:08:44,314 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2013-09-03 08:08:44,316 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201309030605_0019 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2013-09-03 08:08:44,319 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2013-09-03 08:08:44,323 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2013-09-03 08:08:44,323 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - unable to read pigs manifest file
2013-09-03 08:08:44,325 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
1.2.1       vmuser  2013-09-03 08:07:57 2013-09-03 08:08:44 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201309030605_0019   data    MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed! Error - JobCleanup Task Failure, Task: task_201309030605_0019_m_000001 hdfs://localhost:9000/user/vmuser/final.out,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/vmuser/test.seq"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/vmuser/final.out"
```

The file exists on HDFS and another Script which doesn't register any jar and uses `PigStorage()` instead of UDF is working fine. Is there any other way to register the jar and call the UDF?

The contents of pig log file are :

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:145)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Comment: Can you paste the Pig log file? I guess there is some exception happening in your MyTextLoader.

Comment: The UDF MyTextLoader is working fine in the local mode.

Comment: Can you check if your Pig version is compatible with the Hadoop version? Maybe your Pig is compiled with a wrong version Hadoop.

Comment: It turned out that the tool I was using was not compatible with the pig version I had. I installed a lower pig and hadoop version and it's worked. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Might be this link helps you: 
 [Invoking program through java jar used in pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400269/invoking-program-through-java-jar-used-in-pig)
and also give complete path of your jar file so that hadoop can locate it from anywhere.